# Filter table rows using search box on button click

Tags: jquery

This is my keyup function for table filter

```
var $rows=$('#roleListTable tr');
      $('#searchroleName').keyup(function() {
         var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
         $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
     }).hide();
});
```

I am trying this same function on button click

```
var $rows=$('#roleListTable tr');
      $('#searchGo').click(function() {
         var val = $.trim($('#searchroleName').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
         $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $('#searchroleName').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
     }).hide();
});
```

What I did wrong here?and Can anybody give idea for when i click `cancel` button complete table should be display.

https://jsfiddle.net/hzrd8b8t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
$(this) != $('#searchroleName');
$(this) == $rows;
```

So just keep $(this) at that line code.
You can use console.log() to verify it.

Comment: without removing keyup function how its possible

Comment: Why do you need both of them while 2 function do the same things?

Comment: I don't want keyup function.I want only button click function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Rioo/29fba5os/
As the first of my comment, just replace $('#searchroleName') by $(this)

Answer (score 0):

You have to show the rows after clicking on Cancel button...
Just change the

```
$(".searchClear").click(function(){
        $('#searchroleName').val("");
      });
```

TO

```
$(".searchClear").click(function(){
  $('#searchroleName').val("");
  $('#roleListTable tr').show();
});
```

See the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hzrd8b8t/3/)

Comment: What you did on keyup is enough.. apply same logic on button click for "Go".. Enjoye